# Using code (Exec function) in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I cannot use `Exec` function in my Inno Setup script.

I tried execute an example like:

```pascal
var Code: Integer;
begin
  Exec('reg.exe', 'import C:\Support\*.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code)
end;
```

But no success, I have an error:

> period '.' expected.

How can I execute my code (reg file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place your code like this without any context.

You have to place the code into some [event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) in the [`[Code]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcreating):

For example [`CurStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) may be, what you want:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = ssInstall then
  begin
    Exec('reg.exe', 'import C:\Support\*.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code);
  end;
end;
```